# For volumeV′ in restframe S′, what is V measured by an observer in S, wrt to the speed v it is moving in?

Tags: special-relativity

My question is, should you include t alongside x y z in which case volume is invarient? Or should you not consider t and get the result that V should infact change since there is length contraction in x direction?

If the latter is true- why should t be omitted?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The length contraction in the Lorentz transformations is only along the direction of movement. Therefore volume contracts the same way as length, by the first degree of $\gamma$. The 4D volume is invariant, because of the time dilation canceling out the length contraction due to a different sign in the metric, but this is rather beyond your actual question.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. My issue is that does this perticular question ask to focus on 3D or 4D volume? Is there any clue in the question that can help me to choose whether to focus on xyz or txyz? thanks

Comment: I believe it is about 3D. It follows from the meaning of the question. Otherwise 4-volume should be mentioned. It also is clear what the catch in the question is, because $\gamma^3$ would be incorrect. However, if it is a test question, you never know what was in the mind of the person who wrote it, so anything is possible, but 3D is a much safer bet.